# How should I re-use common angular unit test functions

Tags: angularjs

I'm finding that when writing angular unit tests I'm often doing similar things in each test file e.g. compiling and digesting a directive.  I'd like to pull these functions out into a separate library but I'm wondering how best to do this.

I had a look at angular.mocks and saw that it uses the module pattern to add angular.mocks to window, and I load in angular-mocks.js through karma's file array.  I have no problem creating my library that way but was wondering whether there was some kind of require('mylib') statement I can use in my test that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$controller` service to instantiate a helper function. e.g.

helper.js

```
var Helper = function($httpBackend, customParam) {
    this.$httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    this.customParam = customParam;
}

Helper.prototype.mockHttpRequest = function() {
    this.$httpBackend.when(...);
}
```

test.js

```
it('should do something', inject(function($controller) {
    var helper = $controller('Helper', {customParam: 123});

    helper.mockHttpRequest();

    expect(...);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems a little bit dirty though:  it's not a controller after all, just a small module

Comment: You could also use `$injector.instantiate()` which does pretty much the same thing and has a better name https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector . I think you have to pass in the constructor instead of a string though

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a recommended best practice from ng-conf http://youtu.be/62RvRQuMVyg?t=21m8s